# access static content in secured Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a standalone Spring Boot application with templates in /src/main/resources/templates and static content in /src/main/resources/static. I would like the static content to be accessible before authentication, so the CSS loads on the login page as well. Now it only loads after authentication. My security configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        try {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/projects", true)
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The static content in `classpath:/static` is served at the root of the application (i.e. `/*`), whether or not the application is secure, so you need to match on specific paths underneath the root. Spring Boot permits all access by default to `/js/**`, `/css/**`, `/images/**` (see `SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration` for details), but you may have switched that off (can't see the rest of your code).

Comment: Thanks, when I do `.antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()` it works. I have edited my post to include the complete security config. I don't see where else I could have switched off the default behavior?

Comment: `@EnableWebSecurity` switches off the default settings.