# Spring Boot Security + GWT, static resources access 403 error

Tags: spring, gwt

I am fighting the css/js access problem in my gwt+spring security simple application. So, i have secutiy controller with the next method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/notes")
public ModelAndView index(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    modelAndView.setViewName(VIEW_NOTES);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

By the way, I integrated these technologies according to this [article](https://technophiliac.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/giving-gwt-a-spring-in-its-step/). So, thanks to this controller method (I use **RestController**) we've got resolved view (simple as ****):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Notes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" 
href="../static/css/notes-main.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
<!-- This script tag is what actually loads the GWT module.  The -->
<!-- 'nocache.js' file (also called a "selection script") is     -->
<!-- produced by the GWT compiler in the module output directory -->
<!-- or generated automatically in development mode.             -->
<script language="javascript" src="notesgwtapp/notesgwtapp.nocache.js">
</script>
<!-- Include a history iframe to enable full GWT history support -->
<!-- (the id must be exactly as shown)                           -->
<iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" 
style="width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
<div id="notes"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now is the most interesting thing that I have these two errors:
GET http://localhost:8080/static/css/notes-main.css 403
GET http://localhost:8080/notesgwtapp/notesgwtapp.nocache.js 403

I dont have problems with resolving resources for other views, btw.
Please help, how can I handle it? If i miss some important part of code, I will add it. Just ask. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By default Sprint Boot permits all access to `/js/**`, `/css/**`, `/images/**`. But you try to access `/static/**` and `/notesgwtapp/**` which will result in the 403 error (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823863/access-static-content-in-secured-spring-boot-application)).

There are two solutions:

1. Make sure that the `notesgwtapp.nocache.js` and the `notes-main.css` file end up in one of the above folders or
2. Override the SecurityConfig of your Spring Boot app and add the `/static/**` and `/notesgwtapp/**` folder to the permitted locations.