# Thymeleaf: can't load js and css when direct access the page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

**Updated: to describe the question more clearly**

I create a web applicaiton with `spring boot` and `thymeleaf`, everything works fine if I open the login page, then login, then head for the management module or reports module sequently.

The proleam occurs when I type the url `locahost:8080/send/kf/index`(needs to authenticate, but I have open access to all in customized filter) in the browser, the page loads without js and css. In debug mode, I saw `/send/kf` was unexpectly put into the path like the following. I can get the resource if I access `localhost:8080/assets/avatars/avatar.png`.

[image]

The following is the folder structure I put my static resources. How could `/send/kf` automatically added into the url, please help me solve this problem. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: does using `/assets/` instead of `assets/` fix your issue?

Comment: No, the right path should be `/assets/css/...`, but `/send/kf` is automatically put into the url.

Comment: do you use spring-security? If yes this could help. [resource 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24920752/3493036), [resource 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22829754/3493036)

Comment: @DavePateral ... and thats what using `/assets/` should fix, right? so just add forward slash in the beginning of your url

Comment: @Patrick Yse, I use spring security, thanks for your guides, but the problem is not about that. The resources can be loaded if I open the login page, but can't be loaded when I type the url(`/send/kf/index`) in the browser, wihch needs to load these resources, but `/send/kf` is unexpectly put into the path

Comment: In my recent practice, I found add a forward slash works for me, sorry for having not discoverd it earlier. @eis

Comment: @DavePateral yes, that's what I suggested as a very first comment :) added it as an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `/assets/` instead of `assets/` fixes the issue, as otherwise it's a relative url that's supposed to get added to the end of existing url.

Answer (score 1):

you can use spring.resources.static-locations in your application.properties file

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/resources/css/

spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

this is taken form [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)

Note:Static resources, like JavaScript or CSS, can easily be served from your Spring Boot application just be dropping them into the right place in the source code. By default Spring Boot serves static content from resources in the classpath at "/static" (or "/public")

Comment: This is to relocate the address of static resources, right? My js and css is under `resouces/static/assets`, it can be loaded if I log into the site, but fails to load when directly hitting an inner url.

Comment: do you mean that you access this page through a hyperlink ?

Comment: Not a hyperlink, just type url in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution for this question. I don't know how `/send/kf` is put into the url for the static resources, but I think if I put the controller mapping under the root path, this problem should avoid. As I think, the url is correct and resources can load successfully.

```
@Controller
public class ManualMessageController {

    @Autowired
    private MsgTemplateRepository msgTemplateRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/manualMsg")
    public String manualMsg(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("msgTemplateList", msgTemplateRepository.findByStatus(1));
        return "manualMessage";
    }
}
```

***updated:***

The right solution is to use absolute path rather than relative path in the project. So change `assets/css` to `/assets/css` works.